# Javascript remove last character and round up

Tags: javascript

Suppose we have a string like this: `2002`. I want to remove last character and round up last character of result. It means the proper output is : `201`.

note: If the last character is `0` we don't need to round up;

**More example :**

`100` --- `to:` --- `10`

`200` --- `to:` --- `20`

`101` --- `to:` --- `11`

`222` --- `to:` --- `23`

`30006` --- `to:` --- `3001`

**`1299` --- `to:` --- `130`**

`4089` --- `to:` --- `409`

`5099` --- `to:` --- `510`

*Actually it's a solution for Currency conversion **Rial to Toman***

Comment: You mean you want to divide by ten?

Comment: Almost it's true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divide `number` by ten and use `Math.ceil` to round up.

```
Math.ceil(number / 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a=parseInt(prompt("enter a number"));
var result=Math.ceil(a/10);
alert(result);
```

Comment: For real usage, parseInt() should be around `a` variable and not around `Math.ceil` result.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var rounder = function(num){
   return Math.ceil(num/10);
}

console.log(rounder(100));
console.log(rounder(101));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function doYourJob(number){
  var withoutLastChar = number.slice(0,-1); //remove last char
  var toInteger = +withoutLastChar; //Convert to number
  return toInteger + 1; //Add 1
}

console.log(doYourJob("2002"));
console.log(doYourJob("222"));
console.log(doYourJob("1299"));
```

Comment: Very ugly, why complicate?

Comment: @tilz0R Downvote because it is ugly ? + OP said he has a **string** and not a number. Downvote should be used when answer is not helpful

Comment: here is string solution: `Math.ceil(parseInt(a) / 10)`

Comment: @tilz0R Ok then post this as an answer if you want. I wanted to post a step by step answer. That's it

Comment: I downvoted you (and then remove downvote) because this tasks can be simplifier than your example. But anyway, result is correct just now fastest.

Comment: @tilz0R Ok thank you for the explanation. It always better to explain a downvote. Remember that you should downvote when the answer is not helpful and not because it is ugly.